# SQL UNION - Adding Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am currently using UNION on two queries (see psuedo-code below):

```
query1 
UNION
query2
```

I want to add an additional column to my results that says the source of the data. The new column called "Source" would return one of the following: "1", "2", or "both".

Being able to handle "both" is very important because query1 and query2 will have similar results and many overlapping records. If anyone could help point me in the right direction, especially with how to handle the "both" case, that would be greatly appreciated!

Sample:
If query1 has a row "Apple,Yellow,Bob" and query2 has the same row, then the result I'm hoping for is:

"Apple,Yellow,Bob,Both"

The individual queries themselves will not have duplicates, but there may be the same row both in query1 and query2 (as seen above).

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database.  Also, explain how to handle duplicates in either or both sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of an additional column col4 like this

```
select col1,col2,col3,sum(col4) 
from(    
    Select col1, col2, col3, 1 as col4 from table1
    UNION 
    Select col1,col2,col3, 2 as col4 from table4
)
group by col1,col2,col3
```

The records with col4=1 only exist in table1.

The records with col4=2 only exist in table2.

The records with col4=3 exist in both table1+table

Answer (score 0):

add a Source field to both query 1 and query 2:

```
select 1 as source, ...
from table1
union
select 2 as source, ...
from table2
```

Comment: That gets me close - but how does that handle the "Both" case? I did just add an example if that helps explain my question better! :)

Comment: it can never be both, with just a UNION you'll get one line from each query.

Comment: if you want to have Both, you'll need to wrap the UNION in another query with a GROUP BY clause

Comment: Can you show pseudo-code for how to do that? I do want the new column to say "Both" if it's in both query1 and query2. Right now your initial answer is ok but does not handle the example I posted / the "both" case. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) = 1 THEN Source ELSE 'Both'  END AS Source, ... FROM ( the union query ) GROUP BY Source, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT '1' AS Source,
                Col1,
                Col2,
                Col3
         FROM   table1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2' AS Source,
                Col1,
                Col2,
                Col3
         FROM   table2)
SELECT CASE
         WHEN MAX(Source) = MIN(Source) THEN Source
         ELSE 'Both'
       END AS Source,
       Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
FROM   T
GROUP  BY Col1,
          Col2,
          Col3
```

Answer (score 0):

One more approach

```
SELECT col1
    ,col2
    ,source = CASE 
        WHEN count(DISTINCT source) > 1
            THEN 'Both'
        ELSE max(source)
        END
FROM (
    SELECT col1 ,col2, source = 'source1'
    FROM source1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1, col2, source = 'source2'
    FROM source2
    ) u
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 SELECT
    a.col1 , a.col2,
    CASE WHEN MAX(a.Source) <> MIN(a.Source) 
      THEN 'BOTH'
     ELSE MAX(a.Source) END
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
    col1, col2 ,'Source2' AS Source
    FROM Table1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT
    col1, col2 ,'Source1' AS Source
    FROM Table2
    ) a
    GROUP BY 
    a.col1 , a.col2
```

Link to the [Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5d413/4)